# URL and Geolocation of addresses

Tags: php, encoding, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

Is there any function to turn this:

```
1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA":
```

into this:

```
1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA
```

Building a google map using their geolocation.

Comment: i'm also assuming it might not only turn spaces to pluses, but other chars to other chars as well.

Comment: You might be talking about [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) or [rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php).

Comment: str_replace(" ", "+", $address)

Comment: urlencode will work, still turns the commas into encoded chars tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly pass '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA'
Use Following function

```
 public function GetGeoLocation($address)
        {
        // fetching lat&amp;lng from Google Maps
        $request_uri = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address='.urlencode($address).'&amp;sensor=true';
        $google_xml = simplexml_load_file($request_uri);
        $lat = (string)$google_xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
        // fetching time from earth tools
        $lng = (string)$google_xml->result-&gt;geometry->location->lng;
        return array('lat' => $lat,'lng' => $lng)
        }
```

It will return geoLocation of the address in array